# how to use the explode in angular js ng repeat value

Tags: php, angularjs

In my project am using the angular js to get the data from the database.after that assign the angular variable to php variable like

```
<div id="displaycontent" class="searchResDataLine1" ng-repeat="x in values">            
<?$Var="'{{x.amenities}}'";?> 
   <p id='val' value=""><?=$Var?></p>  
          <?if(strpos($Var,'wi-fi') !==false){?> 
                              <div> yes</div>  
                              <?}else{?> 
                              <div>no</div>  
                                   <?}?
```

x.amenities='wifi,pilow,hotwater,rowater'
using strpos how to find the given word is in the string or not.
if is there any other way means how use it to find the givenword

Comment: In Angular Way you need to split your front end and back end. Angular is a  front end (client) framework. So don't use it in PHP.

Comment: ok if using angular js how to find the given string in the above code

Comment: just assign your php variable to javascript and use angular bootstrap to assign value to scope varible and use ng-if to render it

Comment: sorry as a beginner i doesn't how to do it please explain it

Answer (score 0):

Can do this within an angular interpolation statement. php only runs on the server , not in the browser

```
<div id="displaycontent" class="searchResDataLine1" ng-repeat="x in values"> 
    <div>{{x.amenities == 'wi-fi' ? "Yes" :"No"}}</div>
```

Or if it is not an equality check:

```
<div>{{x.amenities.indexOf('wi-fi') >-1 ? "Yes" :"No"}}</div>
```

Comment: it's working,Instead of  using "yes" here i want to print a some html div

Comment: Use `ng-if` or `ng-switch` instead